# Is there a way to remove focus from current item in menu bar and select another link?

Tags: python

Is there a way to come out of the current view in the menu bar and select and click on another menu item using python?

I am trying to automate the selection of menu bar items. The problem is current view of page stays on a link under a parent link. I need to remove this focus and select another item in the list and click open using the href.

EDIT:
My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html')
elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/ul/li[4]')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
elm.click()
```

The list for the menu bar looks like this :

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
    <li class="active treeview menu-open">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
           <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
 <ul class="treeview-menu">
     <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</a> 
     </li>
     <li class="active"><a href="index2.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="treeview">
     <a href="#">
     <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
     <span>Layout Options</span>
     <span class="pull-right-container">
     <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
     </span>
     </a>
     <ul class="treeview-menu">
     <li><a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Top Navigation</a></li>
     <li><a href="pages/layout/boxed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Boxed</a></li>
     <li><a href="pages/layout/fixed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Fixed</a></li>
     <li><a href="pages/layout/collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Collapsed Sidebar</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
      <li>
     <a href="pages/widgets.html">
     <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Widgets</span>
     <span class="pull-right-container">
     <small class="label pull-right bg-green">new</small>
     </span>
     </a>
     </li>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the python code you've tried so far? Is this an app you've written, or are you trying to make a script that interacts with a HTML-based GUI outside of your control?

Comment: Its a HTML based GUI and totally outside my control. Edited the post to add my code. It returns 0 errors but does not click on Widgets.

Answer (score 0):

This worked :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html')
elm = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Dashboard v1")
elm.click()
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/aside[1]/section/ul/li[4]")
for link in links:
    link.click()
```